# how can we allow user to key-in value to combobox in php

Tags: php

i'm a beginner.

currently i have a PHP form where user can either key in value in a text box or select from a combo box next to it.

if user choose to key in new value in the text box, it will be added as new item to the combo box.

my question is how can we allow user to key-in new value directly to the combo box without the need of the text box.

thanks.

Comment: This is more of a limitation of html and has nothing to do with php. There just isn't a combo box control that allows for text input available. You can fake it using javascript, but you still have to use a separate text box and combo box. You can do stuff like align them one above the other so they look like one control.

Comment: thanks Jonathan, anyway Alexandra has give me a very good lead..

Comment: sorry if you guys think this question is not good enough but i still says it is a valid question and the answer just as simple as given by our friend Alexandra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support yet for such a UI control. You could accomplish it by using a Javascript library emulating such a control. For example http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/form_widget_editable_select/form_widget_editable_select.html or autocomplete in jquery

Comment: thanks, this is helpful enough... next question is why my question got devoted to -4.. hmmm

Comment: @m.zam wasnt me :) the people here sometimes can be rather - lets say weird